# Show that the metric $d$ on a Riemannian manifold can be defined using $C^\infty$ instead of piecewise $C^\infty$ curves

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I have seen the usual definition of the distance in a Riemannian manifold $M$, considering piecewise $C^\infty$ curves.

I know that we consider this kind of curves only for convenience (for example it is a device to have a simpler proof of the triangle inequality).

If I consider the metric $d$ defined using $C^\infty$ curves, how can I prove the tringle inequality? 
How can I round off corners of a piecewise path so that the length increases less than any given $\epsilon$?

The only idea I had is using mollificators but I don't know if I can use them here...Thanks!

Comment: Your right, you can establish this result using mollifiers. Just take a coordinates patch at the points where two pieces meet.

Comment: Another possibility to prove this is to leave the curves unchanged and change the parametrization in such a way that you smoothly stop in each point in which two smooth pieces meet (using something like a bump function) and smoothly start the other curve.